# show arabic text in luna php eclipce is incorrect

Tags: php

I use luna PHP Eclipse and type Arabic, but Eclipse does not correctly display this message.

I type:

```
<?php
echo "تست";
?>
```

But it displays:

```
<?php
echo "طھط³طھ";
?>
```

My file encoding is UTF-8 Without BOM

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution.
in eclipce follow this path:
"windows menu/preferences/general/content types"
in right panel expand "Text" and select "php content types" and in "default encodding" box write "UTF-8" and click ok :)
*Good luck*